# My iPad mini 4 randomly turns off when i shake it!

Tags: ios, ipad, hardware

Also when it reboots on its own WiFi is greyed out but when I reboot again (home button+power) wifi comes back. The iPad is 16GB WiFi & Cellular out of warranty. I feel like there is a problem with the internals! I have iOS 10.3.3 on it. Sometimes it also happens when i press too hard on the screen

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You're holding it wrong! - Stop shaking it!

Seriously - you're experiencing problems with defective hardware. Take it to a proper repair shop and get a fixed price on fixing the issues.

You should probably prepare for the fact that buying a new iPad is cheaper than repairing the old.